# Python Gdal write virtual raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, xml

Is there a python module to create Virtual Raster (.vrt) xml files? Rather than writing text strings to a file, I'd like to know if there is an automated way to do this.

Comment: subprocess.Popen(['gdalbuildvrt','c:\\full\\path\\vrt_file.vrt','d:\\path\\to\\image.tif']) - works for me! no need to reinvent the wheel. Read up on http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html to see if there's additional parameters you need to suit your purposes.

Comment: The GeoTiff's aren't geolocated, and need to be referenced via the .vrt files to a separate data set of lat/lon values which aren't uniformly spaced.

Comment: I believe this is a possible solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605680/creating-a-simple-xml-file-using-python

Comment: If they're not geolocated then they're not GeoTiff, just TIF. You should be able to write a world file for each given you know the parameters (Xmin, Ymax, cellX, cellY) http://www.kralidis.ca/gis/worldfile.htm to geolocate them and then call GDALbuildVRT. Why muck around with XML enclosures if there's already a tool that will do it for you... trust me there's too much chance of misspelling a key or putting it in the wrong order which is frustrating and complicated.

Comment: Thanks! The word files assumed uniform spacing between lat/long values? is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the world file contains an origin (x,y) and cell size (dX,dY), also rotation but that is most commonly 0,0. This is the information you'd need to put into your VRT to locate the images in space so I would think it would be easier to write the world file, that way each image is located and can be verified individually and modified should the parameters prove to be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

This was implemented in [RFC59.1](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library) in GDAL release [2.1.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.1.0-News).

```py
def BuildVRTOptions(options = [],
                resolution = None,
                outputBounds = None,
                xRes = None, yRes = None,
                targetAlignedPixels = None,
                separate = None,
                bandList = None,
                addAlpha = None,
                resampleAlg = None,
                outputSRS = None,
                allowProjectionDifference = None,
                srcNodata = None,
                VRTNodata = None,
                hideNodata = None,
                callback = None, callback_data = None):
""" Create a BuildVRTOptions() object that can be passed to gdal.BuildVRT()
    Keyword arguments are :
      options --- can be be an array of strings, a string or let empty and filled from other keywords..
      resolution --- 'highest', 'lowest', 'average', 'user'.
      outputBounds --- output bounds as (minX, minY, maxX, maxY) in target SRS.
      xRes, yRes --- output resolution in target SRS.
      targetAlignedPixels --- whether to force output bounds to be multiple of output resolution.
      separate --- whether each source file goes into a separate stacked band in the VRT band.
      bandList --- array of band numbers (index start at 1).
      addAlpha --- whether to add an alpha mask band to the VRT when the source raster have none.
      resampleAlg --- resampling mode.
      outputSRS --- assigned output SRS.
      allowProjectionDifference --- whether to accept input datasets have not the same projection. Note: they will *not* be reprojected.
      srcNodata --- source nodata value(s).
      VRTNodata --- nodata values at the VRT band level.
      hideNodata --- whether to make the VRT band not report the NoData value.
      callback --- callback method.
      callback_data --- user data for callback.
"""

def BuildVRT(destName, srcDSOrSrcDSTab, **kwargs):
    """ Build a VRT from a list of datasets.
        Arguments are :
          destName --- Output dataset name
          srcDSOrSrcDSTab --- an array of Dataset objects or filenames, or a Dataset object or a filename
        Keyword arguments are :
          options --- return of gdal.InfoOptions(), string or array of strings
          other keywords arguments of gdal.BuildVRTOptions()
        If options is provided as a gdal.BuildVRTOptions() object, other keywords are ignored. """
```